# Manage slug for django

Tags: python, django, unicode, slug

I try to use django-uuslug, to manage unique and unicode slug with django. This project seems interesting, it is better to use an existing project to reinvent the wheel. However I have a question, I would to know if it's be possible to specify one column more, to make the slugify on the current object and the optionnal column. For example if we have a site column and want have slug unique per site not per table.

```
uuslug(self.title, instance=self, unique_per_column=self.site)
```

Otherwise is there a better way to manage slug in django or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a look at the source code of uuslug, it is possible to do what you want like this:

```
uuslug(self.title, instance=self, filter_dict={'site': self.site})
```

this will cause uuslug to filter the queryset of `instance`'s model to rows with the same value of `site` field before doing the uniqueness check on that queryset

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer, it works good. Sorry, I have actually been more attentive, but thanks again for your answer and your time.